# Getting the difference between two frames in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get the the difference between two cv::Mat frames in OpenCv. So here is what I tried,

```
 #include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>
 #include<opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp>
 #include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>
 #include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
 int main ()
 {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    cv::Mat frame, frame1,frame2;
    int key=0;

    while(key!=27){
       cap >> frame;
       if(key=='c'){
          frame1 = frame;
          key = 0;
       }
       if(key =='x'){
          cv::absdiff(frame, frame1, frame2);  // I also tried frame2= (frame -frame1)*255;
          cv::imshow("difference ",frame2);
          key =0;
       }
       cv::imshow("stream",frame);
       key = cv::waitKey(10);
     }
  }
```

the result is always the same a 0 Matrix, any idea what I'm doing wrong here?
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens when you replace `frame1 = frame` with `frame.copyTo(frame1)`?

Comment: thanks @raina77ow the result now makes more sens

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mat objects are pointer typed. After setting frame1 to frame directly using frame1 = frame, both matrices show the same point and same frame also. You have to copy frame value using "copyTo" method of Mat.

Answer (score 7):

### OpenCV Matrixes use pointers internally

The [documentation of the Mat type](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#matthebasicimagecontainer) states:

*Mat is basically a class with two data parts: the matrix header and a pointer to the matrix containing the pixel values.
[...]
Whenever somebody copies a header of a Mat object, a counter is increased for the matrix. Whenever a header is cleaned this counter is decreased. When the counter reaches zero the matrix too is freed. **Sometimes you will want to copy the matrix itself too, so OpenCV provides the clone() and copyTo() functions**.*

```
cv::Mat F = A.clone();
cv::Mat G;
A.copyTo(G);
```

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV overloads the affectation operator on `cv::Mat` objects so that the line `mat1 = mat2` only affects the pointer to the data in `mat1` (that points to the same data as `mat2`). This avoids time consuming copies of all the image data.

If you want to save the data of a matrix, you have to write `mat1 = mat2.clone()` or `mat2.copyTo(mat1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar program and I came across your post, here is a sample I have written for frameDifferencing, hope this helps, the below function will give you the difference between two frames

```
/** @function differenceFrame */
Mat differenceFrame( Mat prev_frame, Mat curr_frame ) 
{
    Mat image = prev_frame.clone();
    printf("frame rows %d Cols %d\n" , image.rows, image.cols);

    for (int rows = 0; rows < image.rows; rows++)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < image.cols; cols++) 
        {   
          /*  printf("BGR value %lf %lf %lf\n" , abs(prev_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[0] - 
                                              curr_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[0]), 
                                              abs(prev_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[1] - 
                                              curr_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[0]),
                                              abs(prev_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[2] - 
                                              curr_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[0]));
            */
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[0] = abs(prev_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[0] - 
                                              curr_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[0]);
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[1] = abs(prev_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[1] - 
                                              curr_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[1]);
            image.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[2] = abs(prev_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[2] - 
                                              curr_frame.at<cv::Vec3b>(rows,cols)[2]);
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: You can omit the loops: `Mat dif = curr_frame - prev_frame;` You could also use `absdiff(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst)`